# python requests.post is always giving 400 bad request

Tags: python, macos, python-requests, macos-big-sur, bad-request

We are trying to upload screenshots to a server from mac machine big sur(11.4 kernel 20.5 version) using python. But the response is always shows 400 Bad request, but the same is working fine from the postman. Any help is appreciated.

```
      token = 'Bearer {}'.format(auth_token)
        url = "{}/screenshot".format(base_url)
        payload = {'date': date}
        try:
            files = {'imagefile': ('imagefile', open(
                image_path, 'rb'), 'image/jpeg')}
            log.debug("file : {0}".format(files))
        except Exception as e:
            log.error("file ERROR: {0}".format(e))
        headers = {'Authorization': token}
        try:
            response = requests.post(
                url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files, timeout=30)
        except Exception as e:
            log.error("Response ERROR: {0}".format(e))
```

Comment: A straight 400 error is usually used to indicate that you haven't hit a vlid endpoint or that your data is not formatted properly. More than likely, this is an issue with your use of the specific API.

Answer (score 1):

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing)

This means your headers are malformed, or your format is wrong.